# Search by position, binary trees C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

I'm having struggles doing my recursive functions in binary trees, I'm trying to make a function that ask for a position and then it returns the value that is in that position, I spent so many times doing changes on the code and most of the time it just die. So if anyone know what I'm doing wrong, I'll appreciate it a lot, thank you so much.

```
    struct node
{
    int info;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
}*root;

class BST
{
    public:
        void find(int, node **, node **);
        void insert(node *tree, node *newnode);
        void del(int);
        void case_a(node *,node *);
        void case_b(node *,node *);
        void case_c(node *,node *);
        void preorder(node *);
        void inorder(node *);
        void postorder(node *);
        void display(node *, int);
        void recupera(int pos);
        int countNodes(node *);
        int busquedaPos(node *ptr,int c,int pos);
        BST()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }
};


    int BST::busquedaPos(node *ptr,int c, int pos)
{
    while(c != pos+1){
        busquedaPos(ptr->left,c+1,pos);
        busquedaPos(ptr->right,c+1,pos);
    }
    return ptr->info;
}

void BST::recupera(int pos)
{
    int y = 1;
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\tEmpty tree."<<endl;
    }
    else if (pos==1){
        cout<<"Your position is the root, so the value is: "<<root->info<<". "<<endl;
    }
    else if(pos>1 && pos <= (countNodes(root)))
    {
        bool found = false;
        while( y != pos && found != true){
                cout<<"ok"<<endl;
            int plz = busquedaPos(root,y,pos);
        cout<<"ok2"<<endl;
            cout<<"Your value is: "<< plz <<endl;
                found = true;
            }
    }
    else if(pos > (countNodes(root)) or pos<0){
        cout<<"\tError: The position that you are trying to use is invalid."<<endl;
        cout<<"\tThe list only have '"<<countNodes(root)<<"' elements. Try with one that is on range."<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a very short main() which runs this on hardcoded test data. This will allow you to post an expected and actual output. This will also allow you to run it yourself, and thus catch and fix typos in your code, so your post is valid c++ :)    "or" should be ||

Comment: What is pos? It makes sense in a vector, where every value has a specific index. It doesn't make as much sense in a tree. There are ways to store a tree in a vector (see priority_queue) but they add extra work re-balancing to make the tree fit, and you already have a root node, so ... what can a position index represent in a tree?

Comment: additional comment: The tree class should not be doing IO. recupera should return an int like you said, not print. It is okay to have debug prints as long as you get rid of them later, but an actual debugger would be better.

Comment: Again, the position is not very useful unless it is a complete binary tree, in which case the best way to store it may be in a vector (making recupera trivial). That's why I asked what the position means. Your actual error has to do with the "c" variable in busquedaPos. Of course, I can't be sure, because you didn't post enough code to run it.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Sorry I didn't put enough code, I appreciate all the tips you gave me, some of them I don't understand them at all, I just have 6 months programming and that's not my career so I just have had 2 classes of programming, probably that's way some of your temrs seems weird for me, thank you so much anyways I'll try to understand them in the future, by the way I did fix it with the same structure, just editing the "while( y != pos && found != true)" conditional and separating the c+1 of every case in my "busquedaPos" function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, I would put in BST class a data member for storing the root.

Then I would redefine your `busquedaPos()` method to some such as:

```
void BST::busquedaPos(node * root, node *& found_node,
                   size_t & curr_pos, size_t pos)
  {
    if (root == nullptr)
      return;

    if (curr_pos == pos) // Is current root at the inorder position pos?
      {
        found_node = root;
        return;
      }

    ++curr_pos;
    busquedaPos(root->left, found_node, curr_pos, pos);
    ++curr_pos;
    busquedaPos(root->right, found_node, curr_pos, pos);
  }
```

And then your class methods would use (as I suppose you designed) this static method. For example, `recupera()` could be implemented thus:

```
int BST::recupera(size_t pos)
{
  node * found_node = nullptr;
  size_t curr_pos = 0;
  busquedaPos(root, found_node, curr_pos, pos);
  if (found_node != nullptr)
    return found_node->info;

  throw std::out_of_range("Position " + to_string(pos) +
              " greater or equal to number of nodes");
}
```

Note that I changed `int` type for positions to `size_t` in order to avoid verification for negative positions (which would not be defined). Also, the return value of `recupera()` is the retrieved key at the inorder position `pos`